# What is "buildQuery" parameter in "aor-graphql-client"

Tags: reactjs, graphql-js, react-apollo, admin-on-rest

I am trying to work with "aor-graphql-client". When I try to create REST-client like in [documentation](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-simple-graphql-client#installation), I get the error that "buildQueryFactory" is not a function. 
As I see, this function is using in [here](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-graphql/blob/master/packages/aor-graphql-client/src/index.js).
From this object wee see that param "buildFactory" must be defined in options or in defaultOptions.

```
{
    client: clientOptions,
    introspection,
    resolveIntrospection,
    buildQuery: buildQueryFactory,
    override = {},
    ...otherOptions
} = merge({}, defaultOptions, options);
```

In `defaultOptions` this parameter isn't defined. In my options I now define only {client: {uri: ...}}, and I don't know what buildQuery means.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you are referring to is from a deprecated package not related to `aor-graphql-client` (it was in fact our first try at GraphQL with Admin-on-rest).

The `aor-graphql-client` package only provides the basic "glue" to use GraphQL with Admin-on-rest.

The `buildQuery` option is explained [here](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-graphql/tree/master/packages/aor-graphql-client#specify-your-queries-and-mutations). In a nutshell, it is responsible for translating your GraphQL implementation to admin-on-rest.

We provided a sample implementation targeting the Graphcool backend: [aor-graphql-client-graphcool](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-graphql-client-graphcool). Use it as a starting point for implementing your own until we find some time to make the `aor-graphql-client-simple` (which will be a rewrite of the `aor-simple-graphql-client` you are referring to).

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

what is the buildfieldlist imported in builduery?

Comment: Just follow the code ;) The `buildFieldList` function, as its name implies, build the list of fields of a specific resource from the introspection query